# Why couldn't the following circuit have an active transistor?

Tags: voltage, transistors, resistors, pwm

I've designed the following circuit as a means of increasing a 1.8V PWM signal to 5V PWM. Currently, I see no operation problems based on the diagram below. 
[image: Chart]

When the signal is **HIGH**, \$V_{c}(+5V) > V_{b}(+1.796V) > V_{e}(0V)\$, which means it should be in *Forward active mode*, Until it hits *Cut-off mode*, because \$V_{c} = V_{e}\$, where current should stop, until the drain capacitor (R2) lowers the voltage enough to turn it back on (very quick).
When the signal is **LOW**, \$V_{c}(+5V) > V_{b}(0V) = V_{e}(0V)\$ thus it should teeter between *Reverse Active* and *Cut-off*.

[image: Circuit diagram]

In my mind, this circuit should work, but a user has pointed out to me that the transistor will never turn off, however, if everything is drained properly, how can this be? As far as I know, \$V_{b}\$ and \$V_{e}\$ should both be zero while the PWM signal is low. The same user then pointed out to me that the transistor can never be active. At first I thought it was because 1.79V may not be enough to overcome forward voltage, but there are many transistors that have operation ranges around one volt. It appears I'm stumped.
Why will this never turn off?
why will this never turn on?
Is said user wrong somehow?

I see people using Higher voltages and doing something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg2Z6l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

and it works very well, with no voltage drop of \$V_{ec}\$ whatsoever! But this circuit only reduces the voltage. Why is this?

Comment: I don't know the specifics, but the issue as I've heard it is because VE will never be higher than Vb - Vf. Typically, you would have R2 between V+ and Collector, and PWM out at the collector. This would amplify the PWM to 5V, but would invert the signal.

Comment: How fast are you trying to operate your PWM and what kind of load does it drive? I'm assuming you are using a micro to drive the circuit, but if that is wrong you also need to discuss what is driving the circuit, too. Capacitances and the fact that there is only one active quadrant may come into play if you need to retain duty cycle accuracy and sharp edges at high rates into various loads. I suppose the idea whether inversion is okay also matters.

Comment: "I see people using Higher voltages and doing something like this" ... You need to look at actual working circuits instead of "something like this". That circuit is somewhat similar (but wrong if the intent is to put 24V across the lamp) to high-side driver circuits that usually use PMOS or PNP transistors, but not with 5V on the base or gate for a 24V supply. Sometimes an NMOS is used, but would require >24V on the gate to turn it on. Your second circuit is still an emitter-follower which will put appx 4.3V across the lamp. Perhaps you should Google emitter-follower (or common-collector).

Comment: The "never turn off" comment was a mistake based on thinking you had used a PNP transistor, which you had not.  With an NPN you have a voltage follower, which does not do what you think it does.  Principally, you are mistaken in thinking the VE will be zero when the output is "high" - VE is your intended output voltage.  The problem is that transistor cannot make VE even rise as high as VB, so your output will always be lower than your input.  To get level translation and bi-directional drive you probably really need 3 active elements.

Comment: While if you know enough about the load to know that you do not need to drive actively in both directions, you can probably do it with two active elements, or for limited cases, just one if you can also accept inversion.

Comment: @tuskiomi Your last circuit does work but it has a \$V_{CE}\$  drop of about 19.3 V with a collector current of 1A.  This tranlates to a rather large power (19.3 W) dissipated in the transistor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftgpjt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Q1 is configured as a voltage follower. The base voltage will rise close to the PWM 1.8 V, the emitter will follow it with about a 0.7 V drop and so at 1.1 V it can't rise any further.* Ic *will be 1.1 mA - if that's of any concern.*

> Shouldn't the transistor just open? How can anyone possibly draw from more voltage than the VBase if the transistor is dependent on such voltages. If this were the operation principal, You could never use a smaller voltage to control a transistor's output of a larger voltage. but you CAN! And these answers don't make sense, the transistor should allow flow until the Collector and the emitter's voltages are equal!

That would be true if the emitter is grounded. It isn't in your scheme.

If the transistor opened any more the emitter voltage would rise, *Vbe* would decrease and the transistor would close off a bit until the balance was restored as shown in the diagram. It's rather similar to the common-emitter amplifier.

[image]

*Figure 2. The emitter resistor, R4, is used to provide negative feedback to the circuit and makes the circuit behave fairly consistently with transistors with varying gain parameters.*

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsress.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. (a) OP's scheme. (b) The right way.*

> I see people using Higher voltages and doing something like this:
>   and it works very well, with no voltage drop of \$ V_{ec} whatsoever! But this circuit only reduces the voltage. Why is this?

It isn't. You have again created a voltage follower. The emitter voltage can't rise above Vb - 0.7 V so the lamp gets 4.3 V and 19.7 V is dropped across the transistor.

The right way to switch is shown in Figure 2b. In this mode the transistor can be driven into saturation with \$ V_{CE} \$ < 0.5 V or so.

Comment: Shouldn't the transistor just open? How can anyone possibly draw from more voltage than the VBase if the transistor is dependent on such voltages. If this were the operation principal, You could never use a smaller voltage to control a transistor's output of a larger voltage. but you CAN! And these answers don't make sense, the transistor should allow flow until the Collector and the emitter's voltages are equal!

Comment: See the update. The answers make sense. ;^)

Comment: @tuskiomi "the transistor should allow flow until the Collector and the emitter's voltages are equal" ... this should be complemented by "as long as the base-emitter junction is forward biased", which is when \$V_{BE} > 0.7\$ V, approximately. In this case, there is no way \$V_{CE}\$ to be near zero because, as pointed out by Transistor, \$V_B\approx 1.8\$ (ignoring the voltage drop  in \$R_1\$), and hence \$V_E\$ has to be around 1.1 V for \$Q_1\$ to conduct any current.  Since \$V_C\$ is fixed at \$V_{CC}\$, \$V_{CE}\$ can't be near zero. That's why most answers here put R3 in the collector.

Comment: @tuskiomi: I've answered your 4 Ω lamp question.

Answer (score 4):

It will not work. The emitter follower has no voltage gain and an offset of about 0.7V so it will reduce your 1.8V to about 1.1V.

The problem is that the emitter voltage increases when the transistor starts to turn on, meaning that your Vbe changes.

You can use it in common-emitter fashion (ground the emitter and take the signal at the collector with 1K pullup to +5), however the signal will be inverted. You can add another transistor and resistor to invert the signal again giving you a level-shifted signal of 0/5V.

---

Edit Eg.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frw7GR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: by 'it will not work', do you mean that it won't turn on, or it won't turn off?

Comment: It will take your 0/1.8V input and give you a signal of 0/1.1V, which is not what you said you wanted to accomplish. It does have current gain, so it's not necessarily a useless circuit, but it doesn't work for your purposes.

Comment: Does the transistor not have internal resistance?

Comment: Unclear on the question, sorry. The configuration you show has no voltage gain and subtracts 0.7V from the input (or gives 0 for Vin < 0.7V).

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. so something like this would be more proper? http://i.stack.imgur.com/bE1Qu.png

Comment: It will shift and invert so 0V in -> 5V out. If you can use that you're done. Otherwise, add another stage to get the original logic back.

Comment: Please see edit above.

Comment: Isn't that the same thing as what I suggested? I don't see how Q1's Collector varies from the PWM input..

Comment: Q1's collector voltage is 0V for 1.8V in and 5V for 0V in.

Comment: @I'm afraid I'm not getting it, If my solution won't work, then how do people have 24V motors running on transistors with 5V signals, and not have any problems? I don't see much of a difference between R2 and a motor (on my schematic).

Comment: @tuskiomi The circuit shown in your question doesn't work in the sense that it can't pull the output to 5 V (when the input is 1.8V \$Q_1\$ is active and the base-emitter junction drops 0.7V, while when the input is 0V \$Q_1\$ is in cut-off and there is no current in \$R_2\$).  As for your circuit [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bE1Qu.png), it wil work (\$R_3\$ may be dispensable, though).

Comment: The load has to be in the collector circuit not the emitter.

Comment: @tuskiomi Are you serious when you bring up 24V motors?? Are you planning on using PWM on a motor with your design? It's very important to know, if so. WHAT EXACTLY is your load?

Comment: @jonk this is an example, not related to the actual situation.

Comment: @tuskiomi Details matter to answers. There is no single approach that solves all problems. Driving a voltage that a scope might _see_ is quite different than driving a motor or a speaker. And the rates ALSO matter as there are lots of AC details related to using BJTs, as well. Everything matters, actually. For anything quantitative, theory requires specific circumstances into which you deduce that theory in a quantitative way. A circuit is a specific implementation. Not a theory.

Comment: @jonk - this is a theoretical question that I asked tuskiomi to post in order to work through the fundamental issues with a proposal that mismatched and had become entirely divorced from the situation where it was originally raised.  The point is the fundamentals of transistor circuit theory.  Practical details do ultimately matter too - but are kind of beside the point when the proposed circuit topology doesn't do what it was imagined to.

Comment: @ChrisStratton For now, I honestly don't know what the circuit is _imagined_ to do. All circuits are, by definition, tangible manifestations in reality and therefore can only be the result of deducing theory to specific circumstances. There can be no proposed circuit "in theory," as a matter of simple definition. But sure, have at it. I'll back off and wait until I have some idea where this is all going. And maybe still after that. No problem. I may be long winded by nature, but I don't want to write a book. Perhaps all is well.

Answer (score 1):

If you can tolerate a level inversion of the pwm signal you can use this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkUdJ7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you don't want the inversion, just use another inverter.  Note that this level shifter is one-way only.

As for your circuit, it will turn off when the PWM signal is off, but the output is at most 1.1V (and probably less) as Spehro said.

Comment: That's what I thought too, at first, something like so: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ha2Zl.png. but apparently that design is wrong too, somehow...

Comment: That should work, have you simulated it?

Comment: Maybe increasing R1 a bit.

Comment: This circuit has (inverting) voltage gain, but very weak drive in the positive direction, since it relies on the *passive* pull-up resistor.  To get a strong drive in both directions requires two active elements for the output, and typically *at least* one more to drive those.

Comment: @Chris Stratton I was just tweaking the original circuit, as the others have also done. You raised good issues, tough. Why don't you post them as an answer, instead?